# Add Gradient on a view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

The following code seems to work using Objective-C however its Swift version doesn't work.

I have tried the following:

- Add the gradient inside the collection view cell
- Add the gradient in the viewController
- Use UIColor & CGColor
- Use insertSubLayer

  ```
  var mGradient = CAGradientLayer()
  mGradient.frame = favoriteCell.mImageView.bounds
  var colors = [CGColor]()
  colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor)
  colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor)

  mGradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.1, 0.5)
  mGradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.9, 0.5)

  favoriteCell.mImageView.layer.addSublayer(mGradient)
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set set the colors of the gradient

```
mGradient.colors = colors
```

Comment: I tried the OPs code combined with setting the colors - it works fine and if it won't show up for you **your issue is maybe that your imageView has a zero frame or is nil or that it has other child layers**

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3

```
let mGradient = CAGradientLayer()
mGradient.frame = favoriteCell.mImageView.bounds
var colors = [CGColor]()
colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor)
colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor)

mGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.5)
mGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.9, y: 0.5)
mGradient.colors = colors

favoriteCell.mImageView.layer.addSublayer(mGradient)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var mGradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
mGradient.frame = favoriteCell.mImageView.bounds
mGradient.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)

var colors = [CGColor]()
colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor)
colors.append(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor)

mGradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
mGradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.1, 0.5)
mGradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.9, 0.5)
mGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: favoriteCell.mImageView.frame.size.width, height: favoriteCell.mImageView.frame.size.height)

favoriteCell.mImageView.layer.insertSublayer(mGradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Hmmm this worked for me in iOS 8. Maybe check out this: https://github.com/agibson73/Gradients/tree/master/Gradients